# Adding vertices ('type') aurguments to list of igraph objects

Tags: r, list, performance, igraph, bipartite

I have a list of lists containing the edgelists of plant-pollinator interactions, for a number bipartite networks. Using the `igraph` r-package I am attempting to convert these lists into bipartite incidence matrices for analysis.

I am having trouble adding vertices (`igraph::V`) to the igraph objects in the list `graph_list`. Note: I would prefer to avoid `for` loop solutions as my complete dataset is a list of 238 networks comprising >80k edges.

Reproducable example of my data.

```
network_list <- replicate(10, expr = {data.frame(plant = paste('plnt', '_', sample(x = letters, size = 10,  replace = T), sep = ""),pollinator = paste('pollinator', '_', sample(x = letters, size = 10,  replace = T), sep = ""))}, simplify = F)


library(tidyverse)  
library(dplyr)  
library(igraph)
```

I am trying to add the vertex sequence to each graph in the list. But the following code is not working as I am expecting.

```
graph_list <- lapply(network_list, graph_from_data_frame) #creates list of igraph objects from list of edgelists   
list_mapping <- lapply(graph_list, bipartite.mapping) #map networks as bipartit   
list_type<- lapply(list_mapping, with, type) #extract list of vertices for each network  
graph_list <- mapply(c, graph_list, list_type) #ATTEMPT to add vertices to graph_list
incidence_list <- lapply(graph_list, get.incidence) #breaks


`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Not a graph object
```

`get.incidence` is expecting bipartite `graph` objects with types argument supplied.

For reference, I am following code which works for a single network.

```
example_network <- network_list[[1]] #select one network for example  
net_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(example_network) #take the edge list and make it into a graph  
bipartite.mapping(net_graph) #make bipartite graph       

OUTPUT:
$res
[1] TRUE
$type
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

V(net_graph)$type <- bipartite.mapping(net_graph)$type #compute vertices ('type') and add as vector to graph   
incidence_matrix <- get.incidence(net_graph) #produce incidence matrix  
incidence_matrix[incidence_matrix > 1] <- 1 #force 0/1 edge, some rows are duplicated in random list resulting in values >1
```

where my desired format of each incidence matrix in the list is:

```
       poll_z poll_g poll_h poll_d poll_r poll_i poll_l poll_x
plnt_v      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
plnt_o      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
plnt_r      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0
plnt_c      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
plnt_x      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
plnt_a      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0
plnt_j      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
plnt_h      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
```

Also it would be a great help to have all possible duplicate values (i.e. values >1) in the list of matrices forced to equal 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `mapply` call using `c` isn't correct. You could write your own little lambda function such as `function(g, type) { V(g)$type <- type; return(g) }` directly inside `mapply`, though there is also the igraph function `vertex_attr<-` which can do the same thing directly.

I tend to use `Map` rather than `mapply`, because it is essentially the same function but never attempts to "simplify" the output the way `mapply` does, which can lead to unexpected results. (`Map(...)` is identical to `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` but requires fewer keystrokes).

At the end, to convert the list of matrices such that 0s remain 0s and all positive numbers become 1, we can do `lapply(incidence_list, sign)`

So your whole code might be something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)  
library(igraph)

graph_list     <- lapply(network_list, graph_from_data_frame)
list_mapping   <- lapply(graph_list, bipartite.mapping) 
list_type      <- lapply(list_mapping, with, type) 
graph_list     <- Map(`vertex_attr<-`, graph_list, "type", value = list_type) 
incidence_list <- lapply(graph_list, get.incidence) 
incidence_list <- lapply(incidence_list, sign)
```

And your result would be:

```r
incidence_list
#> [[1]]
#>        pollinator_z pollinator_h pollinator_a pollinator_c pollinator_x
#> plnt_m            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_k            0            1            1            0            1
#> plnt_l            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_c            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_y            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_u            1            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_b pollinator_n pollinator_l pollinator_i
#> plnt_m            0            0            1            1
#> plnt_k            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_c            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_y            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_u            0            0            0            0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>        pollinator_j pollinator_t pollinator_o pollinator_s pollinator_l
#> plnt_e            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_t            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_o            0            0            1            0            1
#> plnt_p            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_b            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_u            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_c pollinator_r pollinator_f
#> plnt_e            0            1            0
#> plnt_t            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            0            0            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            0
#> plnt_o            0            0            0
#> plnt_p            1            0            0
#> plnt_b            0            1            0
#> plnt_u            0            0            1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>        pollinator_k pollinator_u pollinator_x pollinator_g pollinator_o
#> plnt_a            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_e            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_u            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_w            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_i            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_d            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_h            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_s pollinator_e pollinator_h
#> plnt_a            0            0            1
#> plnt_e            0            0            0
#> plnt_u            0            0            0
#> plnt_w            0            0            0
#> plnt_i            0            0            0
#> plnt_d            1            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            1            0
#> plnt_h            1            0            0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>        pollinator_r pollinator_i pollinator_l pollinator_m pollinator_z
#> plnt_n            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_d            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_y            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_l            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_k pollinator_o pollinator_c pollinator_j pollinator_x
#> plnt_n            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_d            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_y            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            1            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_r            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            0            0            0            1            0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>        pollinator_l pollinator_p pollinator_f pollinator_x pollinator_m
#> plnt_m            1            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_i            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_x            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_k            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_l            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_u pollinator_e pollinator_r pollinator_b pollinator_a
#> plnt_m            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_i            0            0            1            0            1
#> plnt_x            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_k            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0            1            0
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>        pollinator_d pollinator_x pollinator_n pollinator_y pollinator_s
#> plnt_k            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_b            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_m            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_j            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_x            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_k pollinator_i pollinator_c
#> plnt_k            0            0            0
#> plnt_b            0            0            0
#> plnt_m            1            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            1            0            0
#> plnt_x            0            1            0
#> plnt_v            0            0            1
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>        pollinator_r pollinator_x pollinator_k pollinator_j pollinator_u
#> plnt_q            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_o            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_t            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_e            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_p            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_n            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_a pollinator_s pollinator_d
#> plnt_q            0            0            0
#> plnt_o            0            0            1
#> plnt_z            0            0            0
#> plnt_t            0            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0
#> plnt_e            0            0            0
#> plnt_p            0            0            0
#> plnt_r            1            0            0
#> plnt_n            0            1            0
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>        pollinator_g pollinator_b pollinator_m pollinator_v pollinator_c
#> plnt_w            1            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_l            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_s            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_c            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_p            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_x            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_d            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_o pollinator_z pollinator_t pollinator_j
#> plnt_w            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_s            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_c            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_p            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_x            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_d            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            1            0
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>        pollinator_g pollinator_x pollinator_f pollinator_v pollinator_q
#> plnt_t            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_k            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_b            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_s            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_m            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_n            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_z pollinator_e pollinator_n pollinator_w
#> plnt_t            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_k            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_l            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_r            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_b            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_s            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_m            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_n            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_g            0            0            0            1
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>        pollinator_i pollinator_q pollinator_g pollinator_b pollinator_p
#> plnt_p            1            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_h            0            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_y            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_s            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0            0            1
#> plnt_j            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_e            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_m            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_x            0            0            0            0            0
#>        pollinator_o pollinator_z pollinator_a pollinator_y pollinator_h
#> plnt_p            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_h            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_y            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_s            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_z            0            0            0            0            0
#> plnt_j            1            1            0            0            0
#> plnt_e            0            0            1            0            0
#> plnt_m            0            0            0            1            0
#> plnt_x            0            0            0            0            1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I need thank you! I appreciate your explaination is very detailed. Great suggestion of using `Map` and the explanation of the difference with `mapply`.

Comment: @Allan, Very instructive application of *apply functions.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `igraph` and use `table()`.

```
## from question.
set.seed(75498353)
n <- 10 # size of plant, pollinator.
network_list <- replicate(2, expr = {
  data.frame( plant      = paste('plnt', '_', sample(x = letters, size = n,  replace = TRUE), sep = ""),
              pollinator = paste('pollinator', '_', sample(x = letters, size = n,  replace = TRUE), sep = "")
            )
  }, simplify = FALSE)

## create list of incidence matrices.
incidence_list <- lapply(network_list, table)
incidence_list
```

Comment: Thanks this is an easy solution. Cheers!

Comment: As expected, the direct method is faster (5 times).